# Creating dropdown list with data from sql and when post is called, keeping the tab selected

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

Ok, heres my problem:

I can create the dropdown list, but when I try and set the last used tab as selected it runs through the while query and selects the bottom option.

Heres my code:

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT id, description FROM sites"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    $options=""; 

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $id=$row["id"]; 
        $thing=$row["description"];
        $thing2 = $_POST['thing'];
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE='if (isset($_POST['thing'])){ echo $thing2;  'selected='selected''}else{ echo $id}'>".$thing;
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" />
    <SELECT NAME="thing" id="thing">
        <OPTION VALUE=0>All
        <?=$options ?>
    </SELECT> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

How do i set the selected tab to the one it is on after the submit button is clicked?

Comment: I have edited this to show what I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE='if (isset($_POST['thing'])){ echo $thing2;  'selected='selected''}else{ echo $id}'>".$thing;
```

needs to change to

```
$is_selected = isset($_POST["thing"]) && $_POST["thing"] == $id;
$options.="<OPTION VALUE='".$id."'".($is_selected?" selected='selected'":"").">".$thing."</OPTION>";
```

Comment: Thank you, This has worked perfectly. I was playing with the code for ages to figure out a solution. Thank you for your prompt response